# How to I properly prevent systemd suspend using a script in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/

Tags: linux, systemd, plex, linux-mint-21

I'm fairly new to Linux and trying to learn. I'm using Plex Media Server and I'm trying to prevent the system from sleeping while streaming a file. I've searched the internet over the last few days and none of the solutions seem to work. One solution I feel is almost getting me there, but it's not quite working. Here is the script I've placed (and made executable) in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/ (based on [this site](https://forums.plex.tv/t/how-i-got-my-plex-linux-computer-working-with-suspend-sleep-after-inactivity-and-wake-on-lan/341703)).

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
X_DISPLAY_USERNAME=myusername

plexresume()
{
    number_of_sessions=$(curl -s localhost:32400/status/sessions? | sed -n "s/.*MediaContainer size=\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/p")
    if [ ${number_of_sessions} -gt 0 ]; then
        echo "[$(date +"%Y.%m.%d-%T")] Number of streamers = ${number_of_sessions} Plex session active, cancel suspend" >> /tmp/plex_sleep_log
        return 1
    else
        echo "[$(date +"%Y.%m.%d-%T")] Number of streamers = ${number_of_sessions} Plex session -IN-active, going to sleep now   zzzzzzzz........" >> /tmp/plex_sleep_log
        return 0
    fi
}

plexkeepalive()
{
    echo "[$(date +"%Y.%m.%d-%T")] Resuming!!..." >> /tmp/plex_sleep_log
    su ${X_DISPLAY_USERNAME} -c "DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xdotool getmouselocation | grep 'x:1 y:1 '" > /dev/null
    if [ "$?" == "0" ]; then
        su ${X_DISPLAY_USERNAME} -c "DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xdotool mousemove 9 9"
    else
        su ${X_DISPLAY_USERNAME} -c "DISPLAY=:0 /usr/bin/xdotool mousemove 1 1"
    fi
    return 0
}

case "$1" in
    pre)
        plexresume
        ;;
    post)
        plexkeepalive
        ;;
esac
```

I know it's executing because it's printing to the log file.  But even when it's printing that Plex is active, it's still suspending the system. I've manually run the script using sudo outside of systemd and checking the value of $? after, which is 1.

When I use

```
journalctl -b -u systemd-suspend.service
```

I see the following:

```
Sep 26 12:47:03 systemname systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Sep 26 12:47:03 systemname [141890]: /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/plexkeepalive failed with exit status 1.
Sep 26 12:47:03 systemname systemd-sleep[141887]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
```

One time I got a successful result, but I'm not sure how it happened:

```
Sep 26 10:51:45 systemname systemd-sleep[112491]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname systemd-sleep[112491]: Failed to put system to sleep. System resumed again: Device or resource busy
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname su[112556]: (to myusername) root on none
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname su[112556]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user myusername(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname su[112556]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user myusername
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname su[112592]: (to myusername) root on none
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname su[112592]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user myusername(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname su[112592]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user myusername
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname systemd[1]: Failed to start System Suspend.
Sep 26 10:52:25 systemname systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Consumed 2.732s CPU time.
```

Any help on this issue would be appreciated. I don't understand why returning 1 from the script is not preventing systemd-suspend.service from running. Thank you!

Comment: I've also since tried this by doing just 'exit 1' in the 'pre' case, and it still returns the same error, and still suspends.